# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/HttpVerb

Tags: java, android, selenium

When I am trying to run a test on Mobile Browser in java. I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/HttpVerb
    at io.selendroid.SelendroidCommandExecutor$1.<init>(SelendroidCommandExecutor.java:30)
    at io.selendroid.SelendroidCommandExecutor.<clinit>(SelendroidCommandExecutor.java:27)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

HttpVerb class has been deprecated. Here is the [commit](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/46d425d3a5fa8e21cf955d7b41bf436548e4971d)

I have changed from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.48.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.45.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After I downgraded selenium-java version from 2.48 to 2.45. My error gets resolved.

But I don't know what is the permanent solution when we upgraded to latest selenium-java